# Change Gmail Background every X minutes

Tags: gmail

I know how to change the theme in Gmail and change the background. However I would like the background of my theme to change every so many minutes versus once a day. Similar to the way you can set the time in Windows for changing the desktop background.

I have not seen a way to do this in Gmail settings.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to select a theme that changes hourly or at least based on the time of day.

In Gmail Themes there are four types of backgrounds you can choose, [as indicated by the icon](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=112508) in the lower right of the background preview image:

- None - Static and one image only
- Sun - Changes based on the weather, set by your location setting
- Clock - Based on time of day
- Strip - Depends on the day of the week

That's the closest you'll get for now until they allow you to upload or select an album to flip through as a background wallpaper on X time increments.